# X Error of failed request: BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)

Tags: python, bug-reporting, tkinter

> X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request
>   too large or internal Xlib length error)   Major opcode of failed
>   request:  139 (RENDER)   Minor opcode of failed request:  20
>   (RenderAddGlyphs)   Serial number of failed request:  689   Current
>   serial number in output stream:  783

Hello.
I'm using ubuntu 18.04 Mate and I get this error when I execute the python code below. Yet the code is correct.

Here is the code that creates the bug:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Polices")
frame.grid()
ft = tkfont.families()
txt = ScrolledText(frame, width=50, height=20)
txt.grid()

txt.insert("1.0", 'Polices:\n')
txt.tag_add("tagpolices", "1.0", "insert")

for i,f in enumerate(ft):
    font = tkfont.Font(frame, size=20, family=f)
    tag = f'tag{i}'
    txt.tag_config(tag, font=font)
    txt.insert("end", f, tag, '\n')

root.mainloop()
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello,
The font that generates the bug is: Noto Color Emoji

Comment: It looks like this may be the same problem as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629281/gitk-crashes-when-viewing-commit-containing-emoji-x-error-of-failed-request-ba. If that's the case, a libXft bug appears to be responsible for the error.

As @fabien says, the Noto Color Emoji font triggers the error, so uninstalling it would be a viable workaround.

Comment: Thank @David P . Solded with apt remove --purge fonts-noto-color-emoji